# Laravel: Passing Default Values from Routes to Controllers

Tags: routes, laravel-5

I'm creating a simple application which uses a single db table for storing post types. For ease of description I'll just call them `Article` and `Tweet`.

I'm trying to figure out how to cleanly pass the `type` to the controller when creating a new record. Sure, I could just create a hidden field in the form and add the type there, but somebody could edit that and we'd persist the record with the wrong type.

What I'd prefer to do is something like this

```
Route::post('articles', 'PostsController@store')->where('type', 'article');
Route::post('tweets', 'PostsController@store')->where('type', 'tweet');
```

I tried the above but keep receiving errors in my PostsController.

This is what I'd like to achieve...

```
public function store($type, PostRequest $request)
{
    $input['type'] = $type;
    $input['title'] = $request->title;
    ...
}
```

I've been searching and playing for quite a while and can't find anything that works. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not create different controllers for tweets and articles

Comment: About this comment "Sure, I could just create a hidden field in the form and add the type there, but somebody could edit that and we'd persist the record with the wrong type." Mind you that you can't control what is been sent to your application via form. Someone could use POSTMan and other utilities. It's your duty to do a proper validation

Comment: @Digitlimit Yes, absolutely, and I do diligently validate server-side. I could easily check to see what the type is, and if it's not valid just `abort(405)`, and that would work. Just looking for something route-based if it exists. :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem not to understand how `where` works with the route.

The where method accepts the name of the parameter and a regular expression defining how the parameter should be constrained:

Example:

```
Route::post('tweets/{type}',  'PostsController@store') ->where('type', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

I think this is what you need:

```
 Route::post('posts/{type}',  'PostsController@store') ;
```

To post tweets send a post request to:

`posts/tweet`

Or to post articles send a post request to.

`posts/article`